# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED with DNS resolution OVH and Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, ovh

I have an app on heroku which I'm used to address with a .com tld. But for SEO reasons, I want to address it with a .fr tld.

I have made some changes in DNS to do it but the only thing I get is ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

On .com, I have this config on my OVH (french host) which work :

```
matosmaison.com.        0   A       54.228.198.226
www.matosmaison.com.    0   CNAME   matosbricolage.herokuapp.com.
```

On .fr, I have put this :

```
matosmaison.fr.     0   A       54.228.198.226
www.matosmaison.fr. 0   CNAME   matosbricolage.herokuapp.com.
```

In heroku, I have added the concerned domains into the app :

```
matosmaison.com -> matosbricolage.herokuapp.com
matosmaison.fr -> matosbricolage.herokuapp.com
www.matosmaison.com -> matosbricolage.herokuapp.com
www.matosmaison.fr -> matosbricolage.herokuapp.com
```

As you can ry, the .com domain works (maybe from a month ago) but the .fr not.

Any suggestion ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to dig (via [digwebinterface](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=matosmaison.fr.%0D%0Awww.matosmaison.fr.%0D%0Awww.matosmaison.com&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=)) you don't have a CNAME registered for www.matosmaison.fr. (presuming that is the actual domain you're having problems with!)

Comment: It says that I have SOA on www.matosmaison.fr. But I habe tried twice to put a CNAME. And OVH says to me that I have a CNAME in their DNS interface... I'll ask for them for support. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately their support is the only resolution I think you have, it should be a relatively easy thing to fix though - If that doesn't work, you can always move your DNS to somewhere else ;)

Comment: Yes I hope. I have ask for support, I guess I'll have no response before monday. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: You were true, it was a bug in their interface. Again, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use ip address since heroku uses a loadbalancer. You might encounter problem.
I think it's better to use cname like

```
* IN CNAME yourname.herokuapp.com.
www IN NAME yourname.herokuapp.com.
IN CNAME www.yourname.com.
```

Comment: Yes I would like to do it but at the time I asked this question, their interface was buggy and didn't allowed to don't have an A field on naked domain. Since the last month,  you can put on a cname too, so I didn't have the problem anymore.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me ! :)